# Unable to find valid certification - Checkmarx Integration error on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, checkmarx

I am getting the following error while integrating Checkmarx on Jenkins (using windows node).

```
[Cx-Info]: Initializing Cx client [Cx-Info]: Logging into the Checkmarx service.  
FATAL: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused:
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed 
Caused: 
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from xxx server 
Caused:
  java.io.IOException
```

It looks like I may need to install some certificates on Jenkins node. Has anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after installing checkmarx certificates.

Comment: Can you tell me clearly about this?
I have same error when scanning on Jenkins with Checkmarx.

Comment: Try contacting checkmarkx - they will send you detailed instruction on how to install certificate

Comment: I have disabled TLS/SSL on Jenkins server. It works.